# Cannot Change TextView Value Inside Fragment From FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm developing a simple app based on viewPager.
I'm trying to change the text in a textView inside a fragment from the mainActivity.
I tried to call textV.setText(String) right after the init() method(where the fragment is instantiated), but the OnCreateView is executed much later, so the reference to textV is null in that moment. The textV textView is placed in tab0layout.xml, and become != null when the layout file is inflated, and it is referenced inside OnCreateView method of Fragment0. How can I get a valid reference of textV inside my MainActivity? Setting the text from within the OnCreateView works fine, but I need it available in the mainActivity.

Here is the whole java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();//fragment is instantiated

        Fragment0.textV.setText("new text");//doesn't work, now textV is null!!
    }

    private void init() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment0.class.getName()));

        this.mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }


    public static class Fragment0 extends Fragment {

        static TextView textV;

        public Fragment0() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab0_layout, container, false);

            textV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create public method(s) in your `Fragment` and get/set the `TextView` this way from your activity.

You can get the current fragment this way:

```
FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment ) fm.getFragments().get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle `onActivityCreated` and then use the `FragmentManager` to obtain your reference where you can set/get the text as needed. This will be called once the `Fragment` activity has been instantiated and is ready to go. You can then store the reference use later if you so desire.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Fragment fragment = (Fragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.thefragmentId));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the on create function of main activity ha returned then fragment manage r calls on activity created for all attached fragments. At that time fragment view is created. So what you need to do is set the text in on resume of activity. Of you want yo do before just call a function on fragment that sets the text to a string variable and in onresume function of fragment sets that value